# Where can I find a hook to customize the search via Shopware App?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am prototyping a Shopware App right now, where I want to extend the search with our search API. We already have a working plugin in the store for that.

I found those two references for hooks:

- https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/webhook-events-reference
- https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/script-reference/script-hooks-reference

Seems like there is no webhook for the search at all and just a script-hook for a finished search. In the plugin, we could just extend the `ProductSearchRoute` and be completely flexible.

Are search extension not planned right now?

Cheers,
Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to alter the criteria for fetching the products. As of today this is not yet possible with non-self-hosted apps. You could use the app scripts to enrich or replace the contents of an already loaded page as you already mentioned. Obviously that comes with some drawbacks regarding performance. The capabilities of apps are being enhanced continuously though so there's chance search manipulation might become possible rather soon.

Comment: It's even more than just adapting the criteria. Instead of using the Shopware search, I want to use our own search endpoint.

So as we do it in the normal plugin: Send request to our search API -> Return SW the list of product IDs to render

Comment: I see. Unfortunately that is beyond what is possible with web hooks. What could possible work is an app script that is executed before products are fetched. Furthermore app scripts would need to come with access to an http client. Then you could request your API from a script, retrieve the IDs and alter the criteria accordingly. At the moment I can't really say when and if any of those things are going to be implemented.